# how to search line using sed and replace string at the end of the line

Tags: unix, sed, grep

My Requirement is to search line in a file which should have pattern `@$SQL_DIR`and add   string `$IDSS_LA_SCHEMA` at the end of the line. Can any one help me.. ??

Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

Use awk, `awk '/PATTERN/ {print $0, "STRING"}' /path/to/your/file`

Comment: +1, but note that this will add a space before `STRING`.  Simply omit the comma to prevent the additional space.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
sed '/@\$SQL_DIR/ s/$/\$IDSS_LA_SCHEMA/'
```

What I've tried to do there is match lines containing your specified string, and for each one of those, replace the ending with the second string.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. This one is working sed '/@\$SQL_DIR/ s/$/\$IDSS_LA_SCHEMA/'

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat myfile.txt
some line
some other line, with @$SQL_DIR in it
$ sed -i 's/^\(.*@$SQL_DIR.*\)/\1$IDSS_LA_SCHEMA/' myfile.txt
$ cat myfile.txt
some line
some other line, with @$SQL_DIR in it$IDSS_LA_SCHEMA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> cat temp
ngkerng
egerger
erger
ghethe @$SQL_DIRand
jgnv
erger
>
```

see below:

```
> perl -pi -e 'if(/\@\$SQL_DIRand/){$_=~s/$/\$IDSS_LA_SCHEMA/;}' temp
>cat temp
ngkerng
egerger
erger
ghethe @$SQL_DIRand$IDSS_LA_SCHEMA
jgnv
erger
>
```

***Note: This will do an inplace appending.***